# How to transit another ejs file in Node.js

Tags: node.js, express

When I develop `ejs` file, I would like to transit to another `ejs` by clicking button.
But when I try to click and trnasit to `quiz.ejs`,nothing happend.

Are there any wrong point in `ejs` ?

And how to fix them?

Thanks

following is a part of my ejs file.

```
<button onclick = "href = '/quiz'">start</button>
```

And following is my `Router`.

```
router.get('/quiz',(req,res)=>{
    res.render(Views+'quiz.ejs');
});
```

following is a part of my `app.js`

```
app.use('/quiz',Router);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly you don't transit to any ejs file. You transit to another route which renders an ejs file.

So all you need to do is

1. Create a ejs file, lets say 'quiz.ejs'
2. Add a route to render this -

`router.get('/quiz',(req,res)=>{
    res.render('quiz');
});`

And then finally redirect the user to `quiz` route.

`<a "href = '/quiz'>To Quiz</button>`

Also note that you need `<a>` anchor tag to navigate not a button.